# Reference counting in Delphi Interfaces

Tags: delphi, reference-counting

Basic question.
In Button1Click I create an interfaced object. Reference counting after creation is 0.
I pass the object as an argument. Ref counting increase, decrease at the end of the function and as it 0, its getting destroyed. Do I miss something? When I create the object in the first place, I was thinking that ref counting should be 1? lListFilter is not holding a reference to the object?

```
type
    IPersistentListFilter = Interface(IInterface)
        ['{57cdcf89-60ee-4b3c-99fd-177b4b98d7e5}']
        procedure IncludeObject;
end;

procedure FillList(AFilter : IPersistentListFilter);

type
TPersistentListFilter = class(TInterfacedObject, IPersistentListFilter)
    procedure IncludeObject;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

implementation

procedure FillList(AFilter: IPersistentListFilter);
begin
     AFilter.IncludeObject;
end;

constructor TPersistentListFilter.Create;
begin
    inherited;
end;

destructor TPersistentListFilter.Destroy;
begin
    inherited;
end;

procedure TPersistentListFilter.IncludeObject;
begin
    // do nothing
end;

procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    lListFilter: TPersistentListFilter;
begin
    lListFilter := TPersistentListFilter.Create;
    // ref count is 0
    FillList(lListFilter);
    // lListFilter has been destroyed
    FillList(lListFilter);  // --> error
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Button1Click`, `lListFilter` is declared as an instance of `TPersistentListFilter`, not `IPersistentListFilter`.  Thus, no reference counting occurs when `lListFilter` is created.

`lListFilter` needs to be declared as `IPersistentListFilter`:

```
procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lListFilter: IPersistentListFilter;
begin
  lListFilter := TPersistentListFilter.Create;
  // ref count will be 1

  // ref count will go to 2 during call to FillList
  FillList(lListFilter);

  // ref count will be back to 1

  // ref count will go to 2 during call to FillList
  FillList(lListFilter);  

  // ref count will be back to 1

end;   // ref count will go to 0 as lListFilter goes out of scope 
       //    and is destroyed.
```

Comment: Thnks Dave! Its clear now why .create did not increased ref count, but im still confused why FillList(lListFilter) did increase the ref count regarding the fact that it has been declared wrongly as TPersistentListFilter..

Comment: Because `FillList` accepts `IPersistentListFilter` as its argument

Comment: Because the 'AFilter' parameter to 'FillList'  is declared as 'IPersistentListFilter';  'lListFilter' would be passed *as* 'IPersistentListFilter', not as 'TPersistentListFilter'